Migrating from Hilt to Dagger?
Are there any guides for migrating from Hilt to Dagger? The only migration guides I see are from Dagger to Hilt.
Our Android app code relies heavily on Hilt. However, we're looking to package much of the code as a portable module for other applications to be able to integrate. Hilt requires the application to be a Hilt Application, which creates an improper dependency from the module on the application.
Any advice or additional thoughts welcome!

The point is valid, have you found a solution?
